Expo Ejected App - Assets (Images and Fonts) Missing After CodePush Update
I’m working on an Expo project (SDK 51) that has been ejected to a bare workflow to handle builds myself without using EAS services. I'm using react-native-code-push and code-push-standalone to push over-the-air updates. My assets (images and fonts) work fine in the initial build, but after a CodePush update, all the assets are missing.
Environment:

Expo SDK: 51
React Native: 0.74.3
CodePush: 9.0.0
Hermes: Enabled
Expo Modules: expo-image, expo-asset
CodePush CLI: code-push-standalone
Expo Ejected: Yes, using the bare workflow
Bundling Command: npx expo export

What works:
In the initial build, the images and fonts are bundled and displayed correctly. For example, an image path in the initial build looks like this:
file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[id]/MyApp.app/assets/src/assets/images/login/login-header-background.png

What doesn't work:
After applying a CodePush update, all images and fonts disappear. The path of the assets after CodePush looks like this:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[id]/Library/Application%20Support/CodePush/[codepush-id]/assets/src/assets/images/login/login-header-background.png

My Current Setup:
Image loading example using expo-image and require:
import { Image } from 'expo-image';

<Image
  style={{ height: 360 }}
  source={require('../../assets/images/login/login-header-background.png')}
/>

I also tried loading the image using expo-asset:
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { Image } from 'expo-image';

const image = Asset.fromModule(require('@/assets/images/login/login.png')).uri;

<Image style={{ height: 250 }} source={{ uri: image }} />

App Configuration:
Here is part of my app.json configuration:
{
  "expo": {
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["./src/assets/**/*"],
    "plugins": [
      ["expo-font", { "fonts": ["./src/assets/fonts/*.ttf"] }],
      ["expo-asset", { "assets": ["./src/assets/images/*.png"] }]
    ]
  }
}

Bundling & CodePush Commands:
I export my app using:
npx expo export

Then I push the update using:
code-push-standalone release MyApp-iOS ./dist/_expo/static/js/ios/index-123.hbc "1.0.34" --deploymentName Staging --mandatory --description "Hotfix: Updated login button text"

What I've Tried:

Used require() to load static assets (images and fonts).
Tried resolving assets using Asset.fromModule().
Verified that assets are included in the ./dist/assets folder after the Expo export.
Tried to debug paths after the CodePush update using console logs.
Tried changing the jsEngine in my app.json from hermes to jsc, Instead of pushing a .hbc file, I bundled my app using the Expo command to generate a .js bundle file. I then pushed the entire ./dist folder that contains both the JS bundle file and the assets folder.

Issue:
After applying a CodePush update, none of the assets (images or fonts) load anymore. They seem to be missing or inaccessible. I suspect this is due to how CodePush handles assets in a different directory, but I'm unsure how to ensure that my app correctly resolves assets from the new location.
How can I make sure my images and fonts load correctly after a CodePush update?

To fix the missing assets issue after a CodePush update, follow these steps:
1. Update ⁠ app.json ⁠:
Change how you define images by explicitly listing them:
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      ["expo-asset", { "assets": ["./src/assets/images/not-found.png"] }]
    ]
  }
}

2. Use expo-image for Images:
Load images without require(), relative paths, or file extensions:
import { Image } from 'expo-image';
<Image source="not-found" />

3. Rebuild
Rebuild your app (npx expo run:ios) and test to ensure assets load properly
